# Django Rest Framework: JWT Authorization failed

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-jwt

I have an application wrote with Django REST Framework (DRF).
Also, there are such registered endpoints:

```
from refreshtoken.views import delegate_jwt_token
from rest_framework_jwt.views import obtain_jwt_token

urlpatterns = [
    path('api-token-auth/', obtain_jwt_token),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    path(r'refresh-token', delegate_jwt_token, name='refresh-token'),
]
```

Also, there are some endpoints, which requires authorization.

So, I'm trying to extract my token using `curl` client:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://127.0.0.1:8000/api-token-auth/ -d '{"username": "test", "password": "testpassword"}'
```

It returns something like this:

```
{"token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiYTdlMmIyMjItZTZkNy00NjhiLTkxNzYtOTE2YzAwZWRhY2E2IiwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJ0ZXN0IiwiZXhwIjoxNTUwNTEwNDAwLCJlbWFpbCI6InRlc3RAZHhhbXBsZS5jb20iLCJpc19zdGFmZiI6ZmFsc2UsImdyb3VwcyI6W10sInN1YnNjcmliZWQiOmZhbHNlLCJ0ZWxlZ3JhbV9zdWJzY3JpYmVkIjpmYWxzZX0.OExR9TlO3GUisYAu_D86CJ6hgF1EcofpQA0MZ1ENT2c","refresh_token":"1ab03e609d7a7ae05ce104c73858a346a0438e72"}
```

Then, using this token I want to login, using token:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: JWT eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiYTdlMmIyMjItZTZkNy00NjhiLTkxNzYtOTE2YzAwZWRhY2E2IiwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJ0ZXN0IiwiZXhwIjoxNTUwNTEwNDAwLCJlbWFpbCI6InRlc3RAZHhhbXBsZS5jb20iLCJpc19zdGFmZiI6ZmFsc2UsImdyb3VwcyI6W10sInN1YnNjcmliZWQiOmZhbHNlLCJ0ZWxlZ3JhbV9zdWJzY3JpYmVkIjpmYWxzZX0.OExR9TlO3GUisYAu_D86CJ6hgF1EcofpQA0MZ1ENT2c" -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://127.0.0.1:8000/api-auth/login/ -d '{"username": "test", "password": "testpassword"}'
```

It returns `403 (Forbidden)`CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

Why I'm doing wrong?

One interesting point here:

Each request for the token returns a new token for the same user:password pair (is it expected or my token expires too fast)?

Comment: Try without JWT word just the token.

Comment: Could you show us the DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the token you don't need to pass the login credentials or go to the login url like you are trying, the token will provide the authentication. Try accessing a protected url like in the [docs](https://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/) example:

> Now in order to access protected api urls you must include the
>   Authorization: JWT  header.

```
$ curl -H "Authorization: JWT <your_token>" http://localhost:8000/protected-url/
```

Make sure you added `'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication'` to `'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES'` like in the docs.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

Regarding your last question:

> Each request for the token returns a new token for the same user:password pair (is it expected or my token expires too fast)?

That's expected, every time you call `/api-token-auth/` you are generating a new one. The default expiration is 5 minutes, you can change it in the settings using `JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA`. Check [additional settings](https://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/#additional-settings).